# Cannot log in to ubuntu after modifying .profile file

Tags: linux, login

I modified .profile file, by adding some PATH to a program to it. I now cannot login to my ubuntu os. I tried to access via ctrl + alt+ fn but the console does not recognize any command I type. It just says "-bash : no such file or directory". I need to access my OS. How can I do that?

Comment: Until you fix your `PATH`, you may need to give the full path to commands e.g. `/bin/nano ~/.profile`

Comment: @steeldriver can you move comment to an answer.